# Implode data from an array in an array

Tags: php, arrays, buddypress

Goal : Get favorited posts IDs from authors ID.

**Authors ID :**

```
$currentid = $current_user->ID;
$fav_author_list = bp_follow_get_following( array( 'user_id' => $currentid ) );
echo implode(' ', $fav_author_list);
```

*Result : 1, 45, 9*

**Favorited Posts ID from one specific Author ID (1) :**

```
$authorID = "1";
$ok = get_user_favorites($authorID, $site_id);
echo implode(' ', $ok);
```

*Result : 845, 895*

**I want Favorited Posts ID from multiple Authors ID (1, 45, 9) : NOT WORKING**

```
$ok = get_user_favorites($fav_author_list, $site_id);
echo implode(' ', $ok);
```

$fav_author_list should be an unique value and this is my problem because I want get_user_favorites from **multiple values**

**get_user_favorites function :**

```
function get_user_favorites($user_id = null, $site_id = null, $filters = null)
{
    global $blog_id;
    $site_id = ( is_multisite() && is_null($site_id) ) ? $blog_id : $site_id;
    if ( !is_multisite() ) $site_id = 1;
    $favorites = new UserFavorites($user_id, $site_id, $links = false, $filters);
    return $favorites->getFavoritesArray();
}
```

**EDIT :**

```
$currentid = $current_user->ID;
$fav_author_list = bp_follow_get_following( array( 'user_id' => $currentid ) );
$ok = get_user_favorites($fav_author_list[0]);
foreach ($ok as $name => $age) {
echo $name = $age;
}
```

I succeed to get some results from $fav_author_list[0] and $fav_author_list[1] etc, what I want is to get ALL results in same time

Comment: what is not working? your database query?

Comment: It's not working because I don't have any result at all.

Comment: show us this get_user_favorites function

Comment: check this function(get_user_favorites) should return string value

Comment: I just edited my question